# C# - Cannot load assembly 'System.Drawing.Common`

Tags: c#, .net

As the title explains, I guess, I have a problem with executing an application which uses my DLL file. The DLL file uses an assembly called 'System.Drawing.Common' and when I compile the DLL, everything is ok. But when i try to use my application, it throws following error:
[image: The error message in my terminal.]

Tried installing the assembly with NuGet manager, NuGet console and I even tried to copy the `System.Drawing.Common.dll` into my desktop and link this DLL into my DLL, but it didn't help.

Comment: As a starting point double-check that you are referencing the RIGHT assembly (look at the version as well, not just the name).
Then add it to your project.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this problem was that I had to install the assembly not only to my DLL file, but also to my application.